# CustomLinuxScript extensions order of execution

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I have an Azure ARM template which contains 12 VMs. Every VM has one CustomLinuxScript extension resource. I want one CustomLinuxScript extension to execute first. Execution order of remaining 11 doesn't matter. How can I achieve this?

I tried to put this extension in "dependsOn" attribute of all 11 extension. But I get an error: "Invalid resource Id".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Extension can have `dependsOn` property, that being said you easiest workaround would be to make all other vm's depend on the first VM.

The other way to do that is deploy all the vm's in parallel, but have only the first VM configured with script extension and create a nested deployment that would `dependsOn` that first VM being provisioned successfully. The nested deployment would contain all the script extensions for all the other VM's. This will speed things up a little, but would require a much more effort.